# Create a large number of new columns

Tags: r, mutate, across

For a jittering exercise, I want to create a large number of new columns automatically based on a row-wise operation. I have a data frame with unit ids, an indicator measurement per year, and first compute the year-to-year standard deviation:

```
library(tidyverse)
df <- data.frame(id = c("A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B"),
                 year = c(2008, 2009, 2010),
                 indicator = c(12,13,8, 23,21,17))


df <- df %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(indicator_sd = sd(indicator)) %>%
  ungroup()
```

Now, I want to create additional columns which should compute dummy indices for statistical testing. I use `rnorm` for that:

```
test <- df %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(test1 = rnorm(n(), mean = indicator, sd = indicator_sd),
         test2 = rnorm(n(), mean = indicator, sd = indicator_sd),
         test3 = rnorm(n(), mean = indicator, sd = indicator_sd),
         test4 = rnorm(n(), mean = indicator, sd = indicator_sd)) %>%
  ungroup()
```

This all works fine, *except* I want to repeat this test several hundred times. I have played around with across, but not found a workable solution, even if this seems trivial to do.

Can anyone give me good advice how to automate the `mutate`? Thank you!

Comment: Since the means and sds are all the same it would surely be much faster to make a large matrix and name the columns before using as.data.frame.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well you could use **replicate** function from base R

```
# Sample data
df <- data.frame(id = c("A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B"),
                 year = c(2008, 2009, 2010, 2008, 2009, 2010),
                 indicator = c(12, 13, 8, 23, 21, 17))

df <- df %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(indicator_sd = sd(indicator)) %>%
  ungroup()

# First select the number of iterations (if want to repeat 100 times, replace 4 with 100)
n <- 4

# Generate n test columns using replicate
testCols <- as.data.frame(replicate(n, 
                                     rnorm(nrow(df),
                                           mean = df$indicator,
                                           sd = df$indicator_sd)))

# Rename the test columns to "test1", "test2", ...
names(testCols) <- paste0("test", 1:n)

# Bind (dplyr package) the test columns to the original df
result <- bind_cols(df, testCols)
```

And the output is

```
# A tibble: 6 x 8
  id     year indicator indicator_sd test1 test2 test3 test4
  <chr> <dbl>     <dbl>        <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 A      2008        12         2.65 11.7   9.99 11.7  12.8 
2 A      2009        13         2.65 15.0  13.7  14.9  16.5 
3 A      2010         8         2.65  6.12 11.2   9.94  6.43
4 B      2008        23         3.06 26.2  25.2  25.9  23.6 
5 B      2009        21         3.06 16.9  22.5  21.7  23.1 
6 B      2010        17         3.06 21.6  16.7  19.9  19.9
```

Comment: This works like a flaw, thank you so much! I'll implement this into my larger routine (which has more grouping variables) and will let you know whether this works. But I understand that the grouping doesn't matter for rnorm(), so this should not pose an issue.

Comment: I'm glad to help. As long as you correctly calculate the mean and sd for each group and each row within the group gets the corresponding values, the `rnorm()` function will generate random numbers based on those parameters, irrespective of the grouping.

Comment: Correct. The grouping doesn't make a difference and this solution equally works with a very large number of tests.

Answer (score 1):

**using `data.table`**

```
n <- 4
testCols <- paste0("test", 1:n)

library(data.table)

setDT(df)

df[, indicator_sd := sd(indicator), id]

for (newCol in testCols) {
  set(df, j = newCol, value = rnorm(nrow(df), mean = df$indicator, sd = df$indicator_sd))
}
```

**data**

```
df <- data.frame(id = c("A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B"),
                 year = c(2008, 2009, 2010, 2008, 2009, 2010),
                 indicator = c(12, 13, 8, 23, 21, 17))
```

**results**

```
df

   id year indicator indicator_sd   test1   test2   test3   test4
1:  A 2008        12       2.6458 15.1883 10.8849  7.5467 11.0463
2:  A 2009        13       2.6458  9.2771  9.1592 13.6143 14.6580
3:  A 2010         8       2.6458  6.2788  6.0231  3.2603  3.0837
4:  B 2008        23       3.0551 24.3012 24.5867 22.8832 25.1667
5:  B 2009        21       3.0551 19.4236 22.0797 24.5126 18.4231
6:  B 2010        17       3.0551 18.9775 13.3222 10.0405 12.7386
```

Comment: Thank you! This does the job as well. Much appreciated.